# Touch event in vuforia iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am creating an Augmented Reality based iOS app using vuforia.I have integrated Vuforia SDK in my project.I need to shows some objects over the target image while scanning the target image. It works fine. I also need to show some messages over the screen when the user touch any of the object. How can i identify which object the user have touched? How the touch events works when the device get zoom in and zoom out?Please help me.

Comment: See how they implemented touch event in Dominoes sample project and Vuforia having Forum. You can ask Augmented reality questions there https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/handling-touches

Comment: I had checked Domino.But it is not working fine.Do you know how to achieve the touch event?

Comment: I did that by using Dominoes example. I have replaced dominoes 3d models with image target.

Comment: I am new to vuforia and i cannot understand the dominoes.Can you share the details step by step?or is there any document or links which explain the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine ImageTarget and Dominoes sample. Touch event handle in Dominoes starts from EAGLView.mm in the dominoes sample:

```
// Pass touch events through to the Dominoes module
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    dominoesTouchEvent(ACTION_DOWN, 0, location.x, location.y);
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    dominoesTouchEvent(ACTION_CANCEL, 0, location.x, location.y);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    dominoesTouchEvent(ACTION_UP, 0, location.x, location.y);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    dominoesTouchEvent(ACTION_MOVE, 0, location.x, location.y);
}
```

Understand how they handle these touches and try to do the same. For more reference see Vuforia developer forum https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/ios/getting-touch-event-3d-model

Comment: Now i can identify the object i have touched. But when the device get zoom in or zoom out,It is not working fine. ie, can not identify the touch on objects

Comment: Did you handled device rotation correctly like how they did in Dominoes? and If you added touch event correctly to an object we can detect touch event in any zoom level.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I am new to vuforia and iOS. I will give an example. I have placed an object with width 40.0f height 40.0f at the centre of the target image(coordinate 0,0).That is(0,0,40,40).The touch should be work when the user touches inside this coordinates. Sometimes it works fine.But it is not working when the device get zoom in or zoom out.I know the coordinate of the object will change when the device get zoom in or out. I don'd know how to work with  and dominoes sample.